# How to select appropriate data from a list when writing to a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script to make API calls to the Meraki API and need to write certain values to a CSV file. Given the attached screenshot, I have been able to select certain pieces of information from my list, but not anything to do with the "timeSeries" since it seems to be a different sub-section.

[image: JSON]

```
latency_measure = json.loads(session.get('https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/' + ORG_ID + '/uplinksLossAndLatency', headers=headers).text)
```

```
def latency_measure_info(latency_measure):
    csv_file1 = open(name + ' appliances -' + str(today) + '.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    fieldnames = ['Network', 'Serial', 'Uplink', 'Destination IP', 'Test 1 Date/Time', 'Test 1 Loss Percent', 'Test 1 Latency', 'Test 2 Date/Time', 'Test 2 Loss Percent', 'Test 2 Latency', 'Test 3 Date/Time', 'Test 3 Loss Percent', 'Test 3 Latency', 'Test 4 Date/Time', 'Test 4 Loss Percent', 'Test 4 Latency']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file1, fieldnames=fieldnames, restval='')
    writer.writeheader()
    for latency in latency_measure: 
        if (network_id in network_id_list): 
            network_name = get_network_name(latency['networkId'], networks)
```

```
writer.writerow({'Network': network_name, 'Serial': latency['serial'], 'Uplink': latency['uplink'], 'Destination IP': latency['ip'], 'Test 1 Loss Percent': latency['timeSeries'['lossPercent']], 'Test 1 Latency': latency['latencyMs'], 'Test 2 Date/Time': latency['ts'], 'Test 2 Loss Percent': latency['lossPercent'], 'Test 2 Latency': latency['latencyMs'], 'Test 3 Date/Time': latency['ts'], 'Test 3 Loss Percent': latency['lossPercent'], 'Test 3 Latency': latency['latencyMs'], 'Test 4 Date/Time': latency['ts'], 'Test 4 Loss Percent': latency['lossPercent'], 'Test 4 Latency': latency['latencyMS']})
```

```
csv_file1.close()
```

When writing rows to the CSV file, I am able to pick out the Network, Serial, Uplink and Destination IP data, but as soon as I get to timeSeries it will not pull that information as I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: Why not try pandas. It is easier to read and write as well as select columns to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do `json.loads(..)`, "timeSeries" will be a `list` of `dict`s.

```
print(type(latency["timeSeries"]))      
# <class 'list'>

print(type(latency["timeSeries"][0]))
# <class 'dict'>

print(type(latency["timeSeries"][1]))
# <class 'dict'>

...
```

You first access each element of the `list` by its index, and then access the key-value pair of the `dict` using the key.

```
latency["timeSeries"][0]["ts"]
latency["timeSeries"][0]["lossPercent"]
latency["timeSeries"][0]["latencyMs"]

# OR

timeSeries0 = latency["timeSeries"][0]
timeSeries0["ts"]
timeSeries0["lossPercent"]
timeSeries0["latencyMs"]
```

You can either hardcode all the indices (`[0]`, `[1]`,..) one-by-one if you know how many they are beforehand, or you can loop all the elements of the timeSeries list and build the dict value that you want to write.